# Display and save different data in an array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

My goal is to create an array to handle seating in a theater. The array part is fine , but I want the array to display an "x" or a 1 to show if a seat has been taken by someone , but I also want to be able to save a name to that location in the array so that I can check who is sitting where.

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Displaying things has nothing to do with arrays. You will need some UI technology for this (Winforms, WPF, ASP, Console, ...).

Comment: Are you asking us to write the code? Your tags show vb.net, have you started to do anything or this is only the brainstorming phase?

Comment: Definitely not asking anyone to write code for me , just trying to figure my way around the problem . More brainstorm than anything I guess. I picked vb.net because that's what it will be written in .

Comment: How to display something is very specific to a UI technology. You are not even telling us which one you are using. What have you done so far?

Comment: Consider creating a custom class for your seats and storing instances of it in your array instead. That way you can add properties holding information about each seat, such as `SeatNumber`, `IsTaken`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your seating are in a grid style (Cinema)
Create an object like:

```
Public Class SeatingArrangement
  Public Property Row As Int
  Public Property Col As Int
  Public Property Occupier As String
End Class
```

Then, create a list out of it

```
Public Property Items As New List(Of SeatingArrangement)
```

Then you can use Linq to manipulate the items, if occupier is null or blank, it's not taken, if the not null/blank, it's taken by the occupier (name).

For you displaying:
You can using `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event to update the UI and optionally show occupier name on the tooltip.